# Unable to login to my IBM Worklight/Mobilefirst application from IOS devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-security, worklight-runtime

When I am trying to access the application from IOS device getting below error in production servers.

Note: In development environment, it is working fine on Android and iOS devices and in production only on Android devices it is working fine.

System info:
vesrion: IBM Mobilefirst7.1
Dev and Production has same configurations
Dev Operating system:Windows10
Production Operating Syatem: Sun Solaris

E SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication:854'
com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:854)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:715)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:688)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:81)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.subscribeNotifications(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:213)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.NotificationSubscriptionHandler.doPost(NotificationSubscriptionHandler.java:113)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:178)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.service(GadgetAPIServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: You should give some basic information first:
1) What is the version of MFP you are asking? 
2) Is the authentication configurations different between dev and production?

Comment: @VIVIN K  1)Version: Mobile-first 7.1.0.00 2)There is no difference between dev and production configurations.

Comment: is your IOS app registered into the server?

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue occur each time trying to access application? How is the application downloaded and installed?